# ¿Cómo actualizar template de directiva generada con ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suponiendo que tengo la siguiente directiva:

```
.directive("viewSeats", ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            numItinerary: "@",
            numSegment: "@",
            seatMap: "@",
            allTravelers: "@",
            allData: "@",
            flightPnr: "@",
            flightNumber: "@",
            flightTerminal: "@"
        },
        templateUrl: baseEnginePath + "/Templates/FLight/flight-seats.html",
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$compile", function ($scope, $element, $compile) {

        }],
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {

            $elem.bind("click", function () {

                console.log("flightPnr", $scope.flightPnr);

                jQuery.fancybox($('#modalSeats'), {
                    'width': '600',
                    'height': '800',
                    'autoSize': false
                });
            });           

        }
    };
}]);
```

La directiva anterior la mando llamar en un `Loop` algo así como un `ng-repeat` de la siguiente manera:

```
<div imaginemos que aqui es el ng-repeat y la directiva se genera x cantidad de veces>
   <view-seats all-data="@jsonDisplayRS" all-travelers="@jsonTravelers" seat-map="@seatsData" flight-pnr="@listSegments.Item(i + p).Item(17)" flight-number="@listSegments.Item(i + p).Item(8)" flight-terminal="@listSegments.Item(i + p).Item(6)" num-itinerary="@listSegments.Item(i + p).Item(18)" num-segment="@listSegments.Item(i + p).Item(16)"></view-seats>
</div>
```

nota: estoy usando `razor` de `.net`. Bueno hasta ahí las cosas van bien. ya que si mando pintar una de las variables que mando a mi directiva con un `console.log` mi variable cambia dependiendo la posición del `loop`.

El problema surge en el template de la directiva que no se renderea o actualiza con el valor que tengo en el `link` de la directiva. El `template` es el siguiente:

```
 <ul>
     <li>
      PNR
      <strong>{{flightPnr}}</strong>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

(esta es solo una parte del `template` pero para no hacer mas larga la pregunta solo puse este fragmento)

La variable `flightPnr` la mando como parámetro cuando genero la directiva en el `loop`, como ya comente anteriormente si coloco un `console.log` si se modifica, pero en la platilla no y ese es mi problema, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que esa y todas las demás variables de modifiquen en el `template`?

nota: la directiva es un botón es por eso que tengo un `$elem.bind("click", function () {})` en el `link`.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que te imprime el mismo valor en cada iteración? o ¿cuándo das click no cambia dicho valor?.

Comment: el valor cambia en cada iteración, el problema es que no actualiza el template del fancybox, lo que tube que hacer es recompilar el el fancybox agregandole el valor cada ves que le doy clic al boton (la directiva es un boton).

Comment: En efecto, es lo mejor, yo también utilizo esa práctica para las gráficas jQuery que integro a AngularJs. Estaría padre que respondas a tu pregunta con tu solución :D.

Comment: @JoséGregorioCalderón Probé el codigo que posteaste y a mi me funciona bien. ¿Que es lo que te imprime el razor? ¿Valores o nombres de variables en el scope? Si es el primer caso tu ejemplo no tiene ningún problema.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se solucionaria usando las propiedades del scope como two-way binding o sea usando el igual `=` en vez del arroba `@`

```
scope: {
  numItinerary: "=",
  numSegment: "=",
  seatMap: "=",
  allTravelers: "=",
  allData: "=",
  flightPnr: "=",
  flightNumber: "=",
  flightTerminal: "="
};
```

esto hace que angular mantenga la referencias de las variables

Answer (score -2):

Bueno... Es sencillo, lo primero es que tanto Angular como jQuery (fancybox) tienen sus propias variables. Y no es buena idea usar ambas librerías al tiempo. Es como usar `.Net` con `Mono`, pues de poder se puede PERO tu web queda muy pesada demasiado!.

Segun [fancyBox Api](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/) dice

```
$.fancybox( '<h1>Lorem lipsum</h1>' );
```

Entonces, PERO! AngularJS usa el `HTML` como una plantilla. Entonces, jQuery no lee esos cambios, y muchas veces son complicados.

Con facnyBox

```
jQuery.fancybox('<h1>Lorem lipsum ' + $scope.flightPnr + '</h1>', {
    'width': '600',
    'height': '800',
    'autoSize': false
});
```

Unicamente AngularJs toca con [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog']);

app.directive("viewSeats", ['$parse', 'ngDialog', function ($parse, ngDialog) {
return { 
      // Mas... codigo
      link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
          $scope.close = function(){
             console.log('se cerro el dialogo');
          };
          $elem.bind("click", function () {
              ngDialog.open({ 
                 template: 'popupTmpl',
                  scope: $scope });
          });
       }
    };
});
```

> Yo recomiendo solo usar Angular o solo jQuery. No mezclarlo!

Comment: "Yo recomiendo solo usar Angular o solo jQuery. No mezclarlo!" Esto está mal ya que [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) devuelve un api jqLite muy similar a jQuery y si se incluye el script de jQuery antes del angular, este usará el api de jQuery en su lugar lo que significa que Angular **está diseñado** para trabajar con jQuery. ngDialog y fancybox son dos librerías que no tienen relación. Tu respuesta como tal no provee solución a la pregunta.

Comment: Falso, lo que usa es jqLite. Que es completamente diferente! La diferencia es que este es que la librería esta montada en el mismo angular. En cambio "jQuery", seria una segunda librería. Cosa que aumenta la cantidad de tiempo. Por favor Leer! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Este es Jquery -- > http://api.jquery.com
Y este jqLite --> https://github.com/jstools/jqlite

Y mira la cantidad de funciones que tiene y la diferencia!!

Comment: Yo se muy bien la diferencia entre las librerías y sus funciones, también estoy consciente que tienes que cargar otra librería sin embargo tu afirmación está solamente **basada en una opinión** y no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta en cuestión. Angular **está diseñado** para trabajar con jQuery ya que  el [código fuente](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b67d145bf3292a7adbb9766d50f465b05aeddda4/src/Angular.js#L1770) explícitamente busca si jQuery está cargado y lo incluye en lugar de jqLite. Inyecta $element y haz un console.log para que notes la diferencia.

Comment: También es una curiosidad que la librería a la que haces referencia con jqLite tenga un api idéntico al de angular sin embargo las implementaciones no son iguales ([jqLite](https://github.com/jstools/jqlite/blob/master/jqlite.js) y [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js)). Creo que hiciste referencia a la librería equivocada.

Comment: No, 1- Existe una diferencia en tamaño (jQuery y jQLite). 2- La diferencia en funcionalidad es muy amplia (jQuery y jQLite). 3- A la hora de carga es mucho mas demorado cargar dos librerías (Angular y jQuery) 4- Que este diseñado para ejecutar jQuery, los tiempos de carga de ambas librerías bastante demorados. No, Usted esta confundido jQuery con jQLite, cosa que uno es el core del otro. Claramente el core de angular es jQLite.
Y parece que jamas hubieses leído el API de angular. Y aun así, es absurdo levantar dos veces la misma librería!

Comment: Y hago la recomendación, para evitar levantar las dos librerías

Comment: Nunca he hecho una aplicación en la que no haya tenido que incluir un plugin o un módulo de angular de terceros. Tu recomendación está bien algunas veces, **no siempre**. He visto a muchos intentar incluir un monton de librerías y escribir gran cantidad de código "sólo para no incluir jQuery" lo cual termina siendo absurdo ya que el código resultante es más pesado aún. El único caso que le veo es cuando vas a hacer una aplicación que no hace querys complejas al DOM ya que como dices la diferencia entre jQuery y jQLite es abismal. No hay nada de malo en levantar las dos librerías.